# Which is better searching in string or array

Tags: java

I need to store certain id's , and check if one exists there.
Either i can use concatenated string or array/List, which of them is a better and faster way.
This is how actually data is organized :

- Year 1

  - Month 1

    - Day 1
    - Day 2
    - Day 3
  - Month 2

    - Day 6
    - Day 2
    - Day 3
- Year 2

  - Month 3

    - Day 1
    - Day 3
    - Day 7
  - Month 6

    - Day 6
    - Day 2
    - Day 3

Comment: Why would it be better to use a `String`?

Comment: @AlexLockwood : Check my comment at Jon Skeet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would *definitely* use a collection of some form. If you only care about containment, you should use a [`Set<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of some kind (e.g. [`HashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or [`LinkedHashSet<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which will both give O(1) complexity unless you have a significant number of hash collisions) but for goodness' sake *don't* use a concatenated string.

Your data isn't naturally a concatenated string - it's a collection of strings. Always keep your data in the most natural representation unless you have *really* good evidence that some alternative form (such as a single string) will bring you a *meaningful* benefit. Keeping your data in a natural representation almost always leads to clearer code which is easier to work with - and easier to optimize *later*, when you've found where the real bottlenecks are.

Comment: actually the data is organized as per year and months: ex : 2012 contains (jan,feb,march) - for jan - 2,3,5 for feb : 5,7,8 etc : Searching in this tree like form should be tough, so i thought lets create a hash with key as : year:month and values as 2,3,5 . This way no tree like struct will be required, just get the value by key and see if it contains id. What's ur view on this ?

Comment: As above: the data structure you build should reflect what your data is really supposed to mean.  Pretending it's a `String`, or using a `String` to represent data that isn't just meaningless text, is a code smell.  That said, your comment doesn't really make clear what the structure of the data actually is; it's more than a little confusing.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have edited my question, hope it's clear

Comment: @viv: No, it's not really clear. Why are don't you have one object per year, which then has an object per month, potentially with a different entry per day? Or have a collection of dates instead of strings? I'd suggest using `LocalDate` from Joda Time.

Comment: Or alternately, maybe something like a Guava `Table` keyed on both year and month, or something?  But in any event, it still sounds like it could really be structured in a properly organized fashion, with some work.

Comment: @LouisWasserman : kkk will think on something like that

Answer (score 4):

Create a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) a use `contains` method. String or ArrayList will have `O(n)` complexity where as `HashSet` will be `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: `HashSet` is usually O(1), not O(log N). Were you thinking of `TreeSet`?

Comment: Um, it's still confused - you changed the wrong one.